# How to Determine which Radio is Selected, at Document load?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I currently have the following code:

```
<div class="grid-x">
  <div class="cell small-4">
    <label>Product Type:</label>
  </div>
          
  <div class="cell small-4">
    <label style="text-align:center;" for="id_product_type_0">
      Monolithic Zirconia
      <input type="radio" name="product_type" value="BarZero Monolithic Zirconia" id="id_product_type_0" required="">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="cell small-4">
    <label style="text-align:center;" for="id_product_type_1">
      Lifetime Provisional
      <input type="radio" name="product_type" value="BarZero Lifetime Provisional" id="id_product_type_1" required="">
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
$("input[type=radio][name=product_type]").change(function() {
  if (this.value == 'BarZero Monolithic Zirconia') {
      $("#bar_type_option").css('display', 'none');
      $('input[name="bar_type_options"]').prop('checked', false);
      $('input[name="bar_type_options"]').prop("required", false);
      $("#barzero_zirconia_option").css('display', 'flex');
      $('input[name="barzero_zirconia_options"]').prop("required", true);
      $("#intaglio").css('display', 'flex');
      $('input[name="intaglio"]').prop("required", true);
  }
  else if (this.value == 'BarZero Lifetime Provisional') {
      $("#barzero_zirconia_option").css('display', 'none');
      $('input[name="barzero_zirconia_options"]').prop('checked', false);
      $('input[name="barzero_zirconia_options"]').prop("required", false);
      $("#intaglio").css('display', 'none');
      $('input[name="intaglio"]').prop('checked', false);
      $('input[name="intaglio"]').prop("required", false);
      $("#bar_type_option").css('display', 'flex');
      $('input[name="bar_type_options"]').prop("required", true);
  }
});
```

This code takes the user's answer and make additional relevant blanks appear when they make a choice or change choices.  Sadly though this choice does not stay persistent if the user throws an error when submitting the form and has the page refresh.  To which I'm currently trying to tackle the problem by having the code check on page load if a radio is selected with the following code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  alert($('input[type=radio][name=product_type]').value);
  if ($('input[type=radio][name=product_type]').value == 'BarZero Monolithic Zirconia') {
    $("#bar_type_option").css('display', 'none');
    $('input[name="bar_type_options"]').prop('checked', false);
    $('input[name="bar_type_options"]').prop("required", false);
    $("#barzero_zirconia_option").css('display', 'flex');
    $('input[name="barzero_zirconia_options"]').prop("required", true);
    $("#intaglio").css('display', 'flex');
    $('input[name="intaglio"]').prop("required", true);
  }
  else if ($('input[type=radio][name=product_type]').value == 'BarZero Lifetime Provisional') {
    $("#barzero_zirconia_option").css('display', 'none');
    $('input[name="barzero_zirconia_options"]').prop('checked', false);
    $('input[name="barzero_zirconia_options"]').prop("required", false);
    $("#intaglio").css('display', 'none');
    $('input[name="intaglio"]').prop('checked', false);
    $('input[name="intaglio"]').prop("required", false);
    $("#bar_type_option").css('display', 'flex');
    $('input[name="bar_type_options"]').prop("required", true);
  }
});
```

But it does not seem functioning the alert that is in there is to test the value of the radio input but it always shows as undefined.

Comment: $(....) returns jquery which has no `value` attribute. You can try `alert($('[name="product_type"]').val())`, also share your html if you want better answers.

Comment: This worked please make this as an answer so I can go about selecting it, and I will add the respective HTML @hacKaTun3s

Comment: EDIT:  This is actually not the correct answer it cause it to only feed back the first answer even if it is not selected I can show an example if you need to see

Answer (score 0):

After looking into it more this is the answer I found to work the best:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  if ($('input[type=radio][value="BarZero Monolithic Zirconia"]').is(':checked')) {
    $("#bar_type_option").css('display', 'none');
    $('input[name="bar_type_options"]').prop('checked', false);
    $('input[name="bar_type_options"]').prop("required", false);
    $("#barzero_zirconia_option").css('display', 'flex');
    $('input[name="barzero_zirconia_options"]').prop("required", true);
    $("#intaglio").css('display', 'flex');
    $('input[name="intaglio"]').prop("required", true);
  }
  else if ($('input[type=radio][value="BarZero Lifetime Provisional"]').is(':checked')) {
    $("#barzero_zirconia_option").css('display', 'none');
    $('input[name="barzero_zirconia_options"]').prop('checked', false);
    $('input[name="barzero_zirconia_options"]').prop("required", false);
    $("#intaglio").css('display', 'none');
    $('input[name="intaglio"]').prop('checked', false);
    $('input[name="intaglio"]').prop("required", false);
    $("#bar_type_option").css('display', 'flex');
    $('input[name="bar_type_options"]').prop("required", true);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(...)` returns `JQuery` which is a jquery object. `.value` isn't a JQuery attribute, it's a vanilla js attribute for selected elements. To get the value of (specifically) an *input* you need to use the [`.val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) method of jquery while other non-inputs could use the [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) method.
Also, because your form would probably have only one input with a name, your selector, even though being right, can be trimmed down to `[name="product_type"]`.

Here's your code:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  alert($('input[type=radio][name=product_type]').value); // undefined 
  alert($('input[type=radio][name=product_type]').val()); // ...

  // can be cut down to 
  alert($('[name="product_type"]:checked').val()); // ...

  if ($('[name="product_type"]:checked').val() == 'BarZero Monolithic Zirconia') {
    // ...
  }
  else if ($('[name="product_type"]:checked').val() == 'BarZero Lifetime Provisional') {
    // ...
  }
});
```

Comment: This actually doesn't work and always returns the first value in my radio tag at least in my instance that is what I got